# jQuery tooltips in good place only when hovering over label from bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip

I want to add jQuery UI tooltips but they are placed above label. Their position depends on where I scrolled the page. When label is close to bottom of the page then tooltip is close to it. Higher the label is in browser window, higher the tool tip is in relevance to label. Tooltip is displayed next to label only when hover from bottom. I tried position: during initialization but it's not working...

.js

```
 $("label.info").tooltip();
```

.tpl file

```
<label class="info" title="Tooltip text"><img src="/img.png" id="someid" style="float:right; cursor: pointer" title="Something" alt="img"/></label>
```

**Update**:

Thanks for help, it turned out to be jQuery 1.7.1 version + UI 1.8.1 version without tooltips + jquery.ui.tooltips fault. I got new versions, integrated and everything is fine.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net that will help.

My guess is that in the js you can use an offset value from the mouse origin.

Comment: Just add to your jsfiddle <div style="height:500px">Test</div> at the beginning of your html window. There are scrollbars and your script and jquery.ui.tooltip are not compensating for it.
And there is no css, just default for jquery.ui.tooltip.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. There is some documentation here:
http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position

You need to post some code really.

I made a very basic function which is akin to tooltip here: http://jsfiddle.net/wKEx8/

You use jquerys offset() function to position the tooltip in relation to the mouse. I think you are trying to add positioning to the image, which is incorrect.

Thankfully the nice folks at jQuery UI have made the function easier to use, for example:

```
 // getter
 var position = $( ".selector" ).tooltip( "option", "position" );


 // setter
 $( ".selector" ).tooltip( "option", "position", { my: "left+15 center", at: "right center" } );
```